# Passar Parametros de Varios Checkboxes Para Uma Variavel Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, gostaria de como saber como eu faço para pegar os valores do campo value de varios checkboxes selecionados e guardar em uma variavel jquery separado por virgulas, mas sem usar o campo id, já que ele já está sendo usado em uma label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar simplesmente `$(':checked')` como seletor ou ser mais explícito e usar `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`.

Para passar para uma array podes usar o `.get()`combinado com `.map()` que converte uma coleção jQuery numa array nativa e depois vai buscar o `value` a cada elemento/objeto dessa array. Para passar para *string* (julgo ser isso que queres) basta fazer `.toString()` ou `.join(',');`

```js
var valores = $(':checked').get().map(el => el.value).join(',');
console.log(valores);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" value="b">
<input type="checkbox" value="c" checked="true">
<input type="checkbox" value="d" checked ="true">
```

Comment: Mas esse ele não é dinâmico é? porque pelo que eu vi quando executa o codigo ele já faz a verificação de qual está checado, mas se eu checar outros checkboxes ele não faz a alteração do resultado..

Comment: @AlfredoLima  podes explicar melhor o que chamas de ser dinamico? ou explicar o que gostavas que o programa fizesse.

Comment: é que por exemplo eu executei o seu codigo, e ele já me retornou o resultado em baixo dos que estão marcados como checked="true" mas quando eu clico em outro checkbox ele não altera pra mim o resultado lá em baixo, ele continua exibindo os parametros que vc passou via html

Comment: @AlfredoLima  nesse caso tens de ter um auscultador de evento .on('change' mas não dá para adivinhar isso da tua pergunta. Vou juntar um exemplo daqui a pouco...

Comment: Beleza valeu! aguardo.

Comment: @AlfredoLima é isto que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/eudjuctv/

Comment: É isso mesmo, mas tem como você me dar uma força porque no template que eu to usando aqui ele não está funcionando, já no jsfiddle ele funcionou, acessa ai fazendo favor e da uma olhada pra mim? http://www.acaiamarena.com.br/atualizacao

Answer (score 1):

Você tem vários jeitos de trabalhar isso.

Para pegar o valor do check box vc pode fazer o seguinte

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

ou se vc setar uma classe ou id dessa forma

```
$('#check_id').val();
$('.check_class').val();
```

No entanto, este retornará o mesmo valor se ela está marcada ou não, isso pode ser confuso, pois é diferente ao comportamento formulário apresentado.
àra verificar se esta checkado ou nao vc usa da seguinte fomra:

```
if ($('#check_id').is(":checked"))
{
  // it is checked
}
```

no seu caso essa função abaixo deve resolver

```
 $(".checkboxClass").click(function(){
  var selectedCountry = new Array();
  $(".checkboxClass:checked").each(function(){

    selectedCountry.push($(this).val());
  });
  $(".exibirSelecao").html(selectedCountry.join('<br>'));
});
```

vc deve por a classe .checkboxClass em todos checkbos que deseja obter o valor

crie uma div com a classe exibirSelecao

Comment: No meu ele não funcionou, e retornou esse erro aqui no console "jQuery is not defined" sobe o que pode ser?

Comment: troca Jquery por $

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, da uma olhada aqui pra mim pra vc ver mais ou menos como tá meu codigo... https://jsfiddle.net/gjbe7bgs/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gjbe7bgs/1/

Comment: olha ai arrumei o cod